# (VBA) Delete entire row if cell X is less than AND delete entire row if cell Y is less than

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know much VBA besides googling, copying code, trying (and mostly failing) and am having trouble doing the following.

I want to **delete the entire row if the value in column AF is < 60** and then **delete the entire row if the value in column AG < 90**.

I am able to do the first part with the following:

```
'get last row in column AF
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    'if cell value is less than 60
    If (Cells(i, "AF").Value) < 60 Then
        'delete entire row
        Cells(i, "AF").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

But deleting cells in AG <90 fails with the following code:

```
'get last row in column AG
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    'if cell value is less than 90
    If (Cells(i, "AG").Value) < 90 Then
        'delete entire row
        Cells(i, "AG").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

The first part works (delete cells in AF <60) but the second part does not work and I get the following error: "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch.

I assume it is a simple fix that I am struggling with because I don't really know VBA. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should combine both rules at the same time and also delete after you loop through everything. this will be significantly more effecient. See below (untested).

```
Sub DeleteSomeRows()
    Dim killRange As Range
    Dim the90Column As Long, the60Column As Long, i As Long, Last As Long
    
    the90Column = Range("AG1").Column
    the60Column = Range("AF1").Column
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        'if cell value is less than 90
        If Cells(i, the90Column).Value < 90 Or Cells(i, the60Column).Value < 60 Then
            If killRange Is Nothing Then
                Set killRange = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
                Else
                Set killRange = Union(killRange, Cells(i, 1).EntireRow)
            End If
                
        End If
    Next i
    
    If Not killRange Is Nothing Then
        killRange.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that didn't delete either row with those parameters, but I will tinker around with that general format.

Comment: I made a couple teaks that i don't think would make a difference, but give that a try or take a look at it and see if that doesn't solve it. I am pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Note that if you're stepping through your code, the delete will not happen until after the loop (which is where the efficiency gain happens).

Comment: Thanks again. It is doing nothing when adding that code- those two columns remain unchanged. I split it apart to run separately from the rest of the Macro just to check, and nothing happens as well.

Comment: Sorry, I figured you would know to define the `Last` variable but you were clear that this was new territory for you, so that's my fault. I'm all but certain it should work now. I have a test file here that successfully does what you're doing. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g4Zl6WJg0xrPqu7ZLw?e=G8vn0g
Assuming this works, please don't forget to click `Accept`. Thanks.